# Embed Wt based widget in a webpage as iframe?

Tags: c++, web, frameworks, widget, wt

Does anyone know if it is possible to embed Wt based widget in a webpage as iframe? Can multiple copies of same widget be embedded in given webpage (For example, a 3D viewer widget based on Wt, displaying gallery of multiple 3D models in same page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely possible.

You'd make WT::WApplication with your widget as a child of the root().

In the iframe tag, you'd put the src="http://path.to.wt/app".

You could pass stuff to it in the url (eg. http://path.to.you/app?view=22) or via cookies if it's the same domain: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WEnvironment.html#a30810ecfa507bc6f655c38a6f218dc92

---

To have multiple copies of the some widget you could use a witty container: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/

I might not be understanding that second part of the question correctly.

---

In fact you don't even need to use an iframe, you can do it with some java script, and a widget set: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/namespaceWt.html#af4b6ed5fd28b4f5fa141b153c1107349

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It seems widget set is what I will need. Are there any examples or sample code available to see how widget set actually works?

@ I might not be understanding that second part of the question correctly

This is what I am trying to do:  In this link http://www.thingiverse.com/newest/page:1 Imagine each item in the gallery is a 3d viewer wt widget instead of an image. File to be displayed in the 3d viewer widget, will be decided by url or cookies as you mentioned.

Comment: I would make one kind of widget to show a preview, and another to show the whole page when one clicks on one. The grid of previews could be in a layout manager: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/layout/layout-managers - or just in a WPanel ( http://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/layout/layout-managers ) and use CSS float right to lay them out.

There's an example widget set in the source: https://github.com/kdeforche/wt/tree/master/examples/feature/widgetset but I don't know of a live demo.